# Maven quarkus project cannot run quarkus:dev after upgrade to 2.4.0.Final

Tags: java, maven, quarkus

I'm trying to upgrade a multi-module Quarkus project from 2.2 to the latest 2.6.1.Final. The build (including quarkus:dev with -Psomeproject) works on 2.3.1.Final, but when I upgrade to 2.4.0.Final it fails with this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "io.quarkus.deployment.dev.DevModeContext$ModuleInfo.getMain()"
because the return value of "io.quarkus.deployment.dev.DevModeContext.getApplicationRoot()" is null
    at io.quarkus.deployment.dev.DevModeMain.start(DevModeMain.java:151)
    at io.quarkus.deployment.dev.DevModeMain.main(DevModeMain.java:63)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "io.quarkus.deployment.dev.DevModeContext$ModuleInfo.getMain()" because the return value of "io.quarkus.deployment.dev.DevModeContext.getApplicationRoot()" is null
    at io.quarkus.deployment.dev.DevModeMain.start(DevModeMain.java:91)
```

A regular build still works; it is `quarkus:dev` that fails. I simply can't see what's wrong here. What am I missing?
I'll create a minimal solution with the problem as the next step, but would appreciate any pointers.

The project is using Java 17 but the regular build does work and development mode also worked with the older platform.

Comment: Are you sure you've updated all instances of the version?

Comment: Yes, very sure (ripgrep and manual checks and careful reading of maven logs). I've been fighting with this and with some native compile issues for some time now. I've found out why the native compilation fails and disabled those features for now, but I still don't know why this fails.

Comment: Did you find a solution for this issue? I have the same issue upgrading from 2.8.2 to 2.8.3 (and 2.9)

Comment: Unfortunately not. If you find a solution, please let me know.

Comment: Disabling the quarkus-maven-plugin 'generate code' goal allows me to start the application, the consequences of disabling this I've yet to research. Might be something

Comment: Creating an main class as [specified in here](https://quarkus.io/guides/lifecycle#the-main-method) worked for me

Comment: I had the main class from the start, so unfortunately that didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

In order to run Quarkus you have to have the correct version of Quarkus itself, and it's helper build plugin.

Ex. of configuration in gradle:

```
plugins {
  // keep the version the same as the quarkus universe bom
  id 'io.quarkus' version '2.12.0.Final'
}

dependencies {
   api platform("io.quarkus:quarkus-universe-bom:2.12.0.Final")
   //... other
}
```

Make sure that your project dependencies are correct, and the Quarkus plugin nor Quarkus versions are not overridden. Especially check for transitive dependencies, if they do not smuggle some older Quarkus version. For maven:

```
mvn dependency:tree
// for gradle wrapper:
./gradlew dependencies
// for gradle:
gradle dependencies
```

Comment: I'm using Maven, but the principle is the same and I have the correct values for both the BOM and the plugin. They use the same version property.

Comment: Please check if your transitive dependencies are not smuggling something older. Forcing the one version for Quarkus plugin, and it's corresponding BOM should do, unless something is somewhere overridden. If you still have issue with it, it would be good to have an example, so I could check what's still wrong.